# Make Enum.toString() localized

Tags: java, android, enums

I'm developing an Android application and I want to know if I can set `Enum.toString()` multilanguage.

I'm going to use this `Enum` on a `Spinner` and I want to use multi language texts.

```
public class Types
{
    public enum Stature
    {
        tall (0, "tall"),
        average(1, "average"),
        small(2, "small");

        private final int stature;
        private final String statureString;

        Stature(int anStature, String anStatureString) { stature = anStature; statureString = anStatureString; }

        public int getValue() { return stature; }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return statureString; }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to use `Context.getString()` inside an Enum, and I have hardcoded "tall", "average" and "small" to test it. I have defined that `enum` inside on a helper class.

This how I use the `enum` on a `Spinner`:

```
mSpinStature.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Stature>(mActivity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Stature.values()));
```

**Do you know how can I do it?**

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6350364/1025599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume this resource path

```
String resourceBundlePath = "my.package.bundles.messages"
```

In package `my.package.bundles` you may have `messages.properties`, `messages_en_US.properties` etc.

Then, using

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceBundlePath);
String messageKey = "myFirstMessage";
String message = resourceBundle.getMessage(messageKey);
```

`message` will contain the value of the `messageKey` property defined on `messages.properties`. If the current Locale is actually `en_US` you will get the value from `messages_en_US.properties`. If the current locale is something you do not have a properties file for the value will be from the default `messages.properties`

You can also call

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceBundlePath, myLocale);
```

but it is generally better to use the platform locale (have a look at jvm arguments -Duser.language, -Duser.country)

You can have a ResourceBundle for each enum you want to translate with keys the enum element names and use it in the toString() implementation of your enum:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return resourceBudle.getString(super.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I created a simple library which is a part of my big project ([Xdroid](https://github.com/shamanland/xdroid)):

```
compile 'com.shamanland:xdroid-enum-format:0.2.4'
```

Now you can avoid the same monkey-job (declaring field, constructor, etc) for all enumetations by using annotations:

```
public enum State {
    @EnumString(R.string.state_idle)
    IDLE,

    @EnumString(R.string.state_pending)
    PENDING,

    @EnumString(R.string.state_in_progress)
    IN_PROGRESS,

    @EnumString(R.string.state_cancelled)
    CANCELLED,

    @EnumString(R.string.state_done)
    DONE;
}
```

And then use the common Java approach - use extensions of class `java.text.Format`:

```
public void onStateChanged(State state) {
    EnumFormat enumFormat = EnumFormat.getInstance();
    toast(enumFormat.format(state));
}
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="state_idle">Idle</string>
<string name="state_pending">Pending</string>
<string name="state_in_progress">In progress</string>
<string name="state_cancelled">Cancelled</string>
<string name="state_done">Done</string>
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280318/1891118) how to show `Toast` simply.

You can also compile a demo app from [github](https://github.com/shamanland/xdroid/blob/master/example/src/main/java/xdroid/example/ExampleEnumFormatDialog.java).

Comment: can this work on Xamarin? if yes then what changes are required?

Answer (score 1):

I would leave enum as is and use the standard ResourceBundle approach http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html using Enum.toString as the key

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added more details to my question. Those string are defined in strings.xml. And I don't know how can I do it using ResourceBundle.

Comment: Not toString()! Use .name()

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    //java
    return ResourceBundle.getBundle().getString(id); 
    //android?
    App.getContext().getString(id);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are missing some things in your answer: a descriptive text for the reader, also your code won't work because id is not declared.