# Android Toast crash

Tags: android, crash, toast

I have made a client in my android app that connect to pc server. When my app connect to server i want to see "Connection established" , for this i'm using toast but my program crash at startup. Here there's the code:

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

       try {
             Socket client = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 4444);  //connect to server
             Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection established" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             t.show();
             client.close();   //closing the connection

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }
```

i have this problem since i've written "Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection established" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);"

here there's the logcat:

```
    05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at com.example.social_network.MainActivity$myTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:34)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at com.example.social_network.MainActivity$myTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-29 16:28:54.076: E/AndroidRuntime(32436):    ... 4 more
```

thanks

Comment: Please do not change your OP this makes it confusing for others and the answers obsolete. If you have a new problem then please post a new question with relevant information. I have rolled it back to the OP so it is correct.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and follow the link to the dupe and look at @Aman's answer. You are making it more difficult than it needs to be and introducing more potential for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you need to use best practices with AsyncTask. For example check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280318/1891118).

But if you want just to test it quickly, try this:

Replace these lines:

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection established", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show();
```

by these ones:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection established", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
    }
});
```

**FOR UPDATED CODE:**

Replace this line:

```
if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){
```

by this one:

```
if ("Exception Caught".equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
```

Comment: i've refreshed my code

Comment: I would not recommend suggesting to use `Handler` with `AsyncTask`. The class already has methods to handle any need for this and it can just lead to more problems.

Answer (score 1):

`Toast` can not be shown in do`doInBackground()` because its related to UI and you can not perform UI related task in `doInBackground()`.You can use that in `onPostExecute()` or `onPreExecute()`.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Don't forget `onProgressUpdate()` but +1 for giving the best solution instead of suggesting unnecessary things which could lead to more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How to show toast in AsyncTask in doInBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790351/how-to-show-toast-in-asynctask-in-doinbackground)

You cannot call Toast in doinbackground. You should call it in onPostExecute() or onProgressUpdate().

Edit thanks to  codeMagic.

Comment: What solution did you do? runOnUiThread or moving Toast to onPostExecute?

Comment: I would not recommend suggesting to use `runOnUiThread()` with `AsyncTask`. The class already has methods to handle any need for this and it can just lead to more problems.