# Spring get enum values from properties file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, enums, message

I have an enum where values are presented in utf8 format. Because of this i have some encoding problems in my jsp view. Is there a way to get values from my `messages.properties` file. What if i have following lines in my properties file:

```
shop.first=Первый
shop.second=Второй
shop.third=Третий
```

How can i inject them in enum?

```
public enum ShopType {    
    FIRST("Первый"), SECOND("Второй"), THIRD("Третий");

    private String label;

    ShopType(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167144/make-enum-tostring-localized

Answer (score 6):

I often have similar use cases, which I handle by putting the keys (not the localized values) as enum properties. Using a `ResourceBundle` (or a `MessageSource` when using Spring), I can resolve any such localized string whenever needed. This approach has two advantages:

1. All localized strings can be stored into one single `.properties` file, which eliminates all encoding concerns in Java classes;
2. It makes the code fully localizable (in fact, it will be one `.properties` file per locale).

This way, your enum will look like:

```
public enum ShopType {    
    FIRST("shop.first"), SECOND("shop.second"), THIRD("shop.third");

    private final String key;

    private ShopType(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

(I removed the setter since an enum property should always be read-only. Anyway, it's not necessary anymore.)

Your `.properties` file remains the same.

Now comes the time to get a localized shop name...

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("shops");
String first = rb.getString(ShopType.FIRST.getKey()); // Первый
```

Hope this will help...

Jeff

Comment: Be careful with this approach. `java.util.ResourceBundle#getBundle(java.lang.String)` doesn't support `UTF-8` encoding, it is assumed to use the `ISO 8859-1` character encoding. If your localisation files contains such characters, you need to use `java.util.Properties#load(java.io.Reader)`